BlueNRG2 Primary Services increase
I am using BLUENRG-2 (STEVAL-IDB008V1M) and I have created new 4 custom primary services but only 3 are visible at a time. Is there any way to increase its count?
I tried initialising all 4 services but only 1st 3 are shown in BLE scanner application. And 4th one never starts.
Thank you for the help

Have you asked STM's Service Team/Application Field Engineers for help?

I have posted same query on STMicroelectronics Community. Is there any other way to get help from? @Risto
